# Concerning the problem of finding the number of invertible nxn random {1,0} matrcies

Tags: probability, combinatorics, matrices, random-matrices

In a few more words, if we look at the space of all nxn matrices (over a field of characteristic 0) with only 1 or 0 as an element in them ("binary matrices"), how many of them are invertible for each n? There is a short sequence on the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A046747), and from what I can tell by reading the papers referred on that page, it appears that everyone seems to be finding the (bounds of the) probability that a certain nxn matrix is invertible out of all the {1,0} matrices of same dimension.

My question is whether or not there is a way of figuring out an explicit formula that would give the total number of invertible matrices given some size n? Maybe there is some explicit proof that such a formula cannot be achieved? Or is it simply considered out of reach by modern machinery?

I also understand that brute-forcing the problem is nigh-impossible, so empirical evidence is going to be scant for a *long* time. Though empirical evidence isn't going to be particularly useful for a proof anyway...

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/18636/number-of-invertible-0-1-real-matrices

Comment: I have, but I was wondering why can't we figure out an explicit solution (as opposed to finding the bounds) just like we have already for matrices over finite fields.